# A5/1 security algorithm

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I want the encryption and decryption algorithm for A5/1 security code. Where can find these codes.

Comment: [I can haz teh codez? Kthxbai!](http://cryptome.org/jya/a51-pi.htm)

Answer (score 3):

The wikipedia article ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A5/1 ) was recommended to my as being a reasonable description by my flatmate whom is currently undertaking a masters in security and digital forensics.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an implementation in C of the A5/1 and A5/2 encryption algorithms by Marc Briceno, Ian Goldberg, and David Wagner. A5/1 and A5/2 are XOR-based stream ciphers, so encryption and decryption are the same operation:

- [A pedagogical implementation of the GSM A5/1 and A5/2 "voice privacy" encryption algorithms.](http://www.scard.org/gsm/a51.html)

Note the warning from the authors:

> The source code below is optimized for instructional value and
>   clarity. Performance will be terrible, but that's not the point.

Answer (score 2):

The source code below is optimized for instructional value and clarity:
http://www.scard.org/gsm/a51.html